# Why can't I create a ForeignKey field to a child class in django?

Tags: python, django

Class Folder inherits from class Item, which has a foreign key to Folder:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    # some fields
    folder = models.ForeignKey('Folder')

class Folder(Item):
    # some fields
```

When I try to run this, I get the error:

```
app.item: 'folder' has a relation with model Folder, which has either not been installed or is abstract
```

I thought the correct thing to do here was to put the model name in quotes, which I have done, but it doesn't seem to help. What should I do to make this work?

Edit: Clarified question using meaningful class names

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

Comment: I've read that, and didn't find it to cover this case. `A` is not an abstract class. I know that if an instance of `B` is an `A`, I can get it with `A.b`, but I'm trying to link it to a different object entirely.

Comment: For starters this is conceptually wrong. `A` has a ForeignKey to `B` and `B` inherits `A` *along* with `A`'s reference to `B` again.

Comment: That is intended. I want both `A` and `B` to have a ForeignKey to `B`.

Comment: I don't think you understand. This is an infinite relationship definition. None of the 2 models manage to get defined.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it now. Perhaps what I need is an abstract class with a ForeignKey to B that both A and B inherit from?

Comment: It would be nice to describe the real world situation you're trying to describe in your database, because I can't tell what exactly you need.

Comment: I have Items (`A`), some of which are Folders (`B`). I want both classes to have a reference to at most one Folder, so that Items and Folders can be in Folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have Items (A), some of which are Folders (B). I want both classes
>   to have a reference to at most one Folder

It doesn't make much sense(to me) what you're trying to do but this can be achieved
as follows:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    # some fields
    is_folder = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    some_other_folder = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
```

And then check with python code that if `is_folder==False`, that `some_other_folder`
is not None(null).

So actually you don't need 2 models.

Comment: That's a very interesting idea.

Comment: To extend on your answer, I can still have a `Folder` class by creating a Proxy model that changes the default field value. See https://gist.github.com/4088912

Comment: @hughes I think what you did there is even cleaner and more django-ish. Very nice.